# Fix Jumping in the air (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making my first Game and now I have a problem: I have a jump button when i press it I am jumping but when I am in the air I can press it again and jump in the air again. How can fix that, so I can jump only on the ground. Here is my Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }

    public void Jump()
    {

        rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

}
```

Comment: So you need to create the logic to prevent that. That's not really something you should be asking on SO, since *you* have to know what the logic is you want

Comment: I editet my question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need a boolean (isGrounded). Then you have to check the collision between the player and the ground with

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Ground") //you need to add a tag to your Ground, like "Ground"
    {
       isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

And then in the Update method add this code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        Jump();
    }
```

Comment: oh I know, I misstyped at the OnCollisionEnter2D method, write isGrounded = true;

Comment: Maybe its becuase you wrote  Input.GetKeyDown but it has to be the button because i have a button and when i press it the player jumps

Comment: Ok now it works with space, but not with the button,i can still jump multiple times

Comment: I think because, you have to add "isGrounded = false;" into Jump();

Comment: I did it. Should i send you my Code again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isGrounded = false;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movement = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground") //you need to add a tag to your Ground, like "Ground"
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
    public void Jump()
    {

        rigidBody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
     void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            isGrounded = false;
            Jump();
        }
    }
}
```